# How to Convert RJS Template to Coffeescript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, rjs

Does anyone know how to convert this simple bit of RJS code into coffee-script?

```
page.call 'RecordSelect.render_page', record_select_id, render_record_select(:partial => 'list', :locals => {:page => @page})
```

It's late and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I discovered you could simply use this in an erb file:

```
RecordSelect.render_page('<%= record_select_id %>', '<%= escape_javascript(render_record_select(:partial => 'list', :locals => {:page => @page})) %>');
```

Which is I guess why I couldn't figure out how to make it straight coffee script. Like I said, it was late . . .

Comment: it's safer to write <%= something.to_json %>